# glibc install from source doesn't create lib folder

Tags: linux, rhel, glibc

I am on a redhat box
`Linux version 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-042.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jan 12 15:07:59 EST 2018` (only user rights)

and need to install glic_2.14 as I am getting the following error from  different library `'/lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/q//l64/./p.so)`

After downloading the tarball from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/), I followed the steps described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107733/5379182) to install. But when I look into the glibc directory after `make install` I don't see a `/lib` folder just

- `/tmp/glibc-2.14/libio` and
- `/tmp/glibc-2.14/libidn`

and they don't contain archive libraries (.so) but just .c files.

Unsurprisingly, when I add them to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the error above doesn't go away.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please update your question to show exactly the commands you used. I can see examples are in the referenced question but it's all too easy to miss out a step accidentally, so please show us what you've tried. (For example, you're referencing `/tmp/glibc-2.14` but the referenced question doesn't mention that anywhere.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it turned out that adding the build directory `tmp/glibc-2.14/build/` (which contains `libc.so.6`) to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solved the problem.